# Owl carousel 2 стрелки

Tags: html, css, jquery

Есть верстка с несколькими каруселями на сайте https://neotwalker.github.io/ProductFit
При разных разрешениях экрана, стрелки летают по всему сайту, можно ли как-то поставить стрелки сбоку без Position: absolute?
Как реализовал в js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var companies = $('.companies-slider');
    companies.owlCarousel({
        nav: true,
        dots: false,
        responsiveClass:true,
        responsive: {
            0:{
                items: 1
            },
            480:{
                items: 1
            },
            768:{
                items: 2
            },
            1024:{
                items: 3
            },
            1440:{
                items: 4
            }
        },
        navText: ['<i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
                                '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>'],
    });
    if($(window).innerWidth() <= 1358){
        $('.advantages-slider').owlCarousel({
            nav: true,
            dots: false,
            responsiveClass:true,
            responsive: {
                0:{
                    items: 1
                },
                480:{
                    items: 1
                },
                768:{
                    items: 2
                },
                1024:{
                    items: 3
                },
                1440:{
                    items: 4
                }
            },
            navText: ['<i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
                                '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>'],
        });
        $('.projects-list').owlCarousel({
            nav: true,
            dots: false,
            responsiveClass:true,
            responsive: {
                0:{
                    items: 1
                },
                480:{
                    items: 1
                }
            },
            navText: ['<i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
                                '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>'],
        });
        var services = $(".services-list");
        services.owlCarousel({
            dots: false,
            nav: true,
            responsive: {
                0:{
                    items: 1
                },
                480:{
                    items: 1
                },
                768:{
                    items: 2
                },
                1024:{
                    items: 3
                },
                1440:{
                    items: 4
                }
            },
            navText: ['<i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
                                '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>'],
        });
    }
    var slider = $(".banner-slider");
        slider.owlCarousel({
            dots: false,
            nav: true,
            items: 1,
            responsiveClass:true,
            navText: ['<i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
                                '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>'],
    });
    var slider_case = $(".header-case");
        slider_case.owlCarousel({
            dots: true,
            nav: true,
            items: 1,
            responsiveClass:true,
            navText: ['<i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
                                '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>'],
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не добавляйте стрелкам top: 405%, это ужас какой-то. И используйте position: relative на родительских блоках, чтобы ограничить область для внутренних position: absolute. В Вашем случае лучше будет сделать так, чтобы стрелки были по середине блока и не вылезали из него:

```
.banner{
    position: relative;
}
.banner-slider button.owl-prev, .banner-slider button.owl-next {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Остальные карусели сделайте по аналогии с этим.

Comment: Спасибо, совсем из головы вылетело, не заметил, что не поставил position: relative.